# This custom async hook is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this custom hook to get the current user from firebase:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from "../firebase/auth-service"

const useFirebaseAuthentication = (firebase) => {
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

    try {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
            if (user) {
                setAuthUser(user)
            } else {
                setAuthUser(null);
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }

    return authUser
}

export default useFirebaseAuthentication;
```

When I print on the screen the current user from this custom hook - I get the result as expected.
When I use the hook and try to get the user - I get null.

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with putting logs in different parts of the code to find out if it's null because there was no user in the auth or it returned before waiting for the auth to happen.

Comment: In the place where I want to use the hook - I don't get the user. (the printing happens here first)
In the hook - I get the user. (the printing happens second)

Comment: "When I use the hook and try to get the user - I get null." Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show how you're using the hook. The problem is more likely to be in there, than in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `useState` here is appropriate, don't you get any console warnings? A hook is just a `js` function as any other, it's not a `React` component!

Try to use a local variable instead...

**edit**

`useState` is a hook, therefore you should be getting this warning:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

It's exactly what's a problem here: you use a hook NOT inside the body of a react functional component, you use it in an ordinary js function.

Comment: Can you further explain?

Comment: I've added an esit. If the answer is satisfactory, please mark it as a correct one